# How do I copy the beginning of multiple files in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, unix-head

I want to copy a bunch of files (*.txt) from one directory to another in Ubuntu. I want to reduce them in size, so I am using head to get the first 100 lines of each.

I want the new files to keep their original names but be in the subdirectory `small/`.
I have tried:

```
head -n 100 *.txt > small/*.txt
```

but this creates one file called `*.txt`.
I have also tried:

```
head -n 100 *.txt > small/
```

but this gives `Is a directory` error.

It's got to be easy right, but I am pretty bad at Linux.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for f in *.txt; do
  head -n 100 $f > small/$f
done
```

Comment: may be good do quote `$f` to prevent cases when the file name contains spaces. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create a loop instead:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    head -n 100 "$file" > small/"$file"
done
```

This loops through all the `.txt` files performing a `head -n 100` in all of them and outputting into a new file in the `small/` directory.